# WAMP and pcntl_fork

Tags: php, wamp

Is there a way to make pcntl_fork work in WAMP? I need to develop a forking solution and test it locally.

Comment: You could try to run/compile it under Cygwin, where pcntl is more likely to function. Else you could handicraft something via the w32api extension if you dare (and if that's still available).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  The [PCNTL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php) extension requires *nix platforms.

Now, with that said, what are you trying to do, and can you solve it without forking...?

**Edit:** Some alternatives to launching background processes:

- Unix/Linux:

  ```
   exec('nohup php yourscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
  ```
- Windows;

  ```
   $com = new Com('WScript.shell');
   $com->run('php yourscript.php', 10, false);
  ```

  For documentation on the arguments, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I need to have concurrent processes running. I can implement using cron (and using the DB to manage the number of processes running). However, say I wanted 10 concurrent processes running, I would need the cron to call a particular script 10 times -- in 1 minute increments -- in order to get all 10 scripts running (meaning, it'll take a full 10 minutes before I get the desired number of concurrent scripts). Alternatively, I can have have "dummy" functions call the same script (e.g. foo_1 calls foo, foo_2 calls foo, etc.) and have the cron call foo_1, foo_2, etc. every minute. Seems kludgy.

Comment: @Stack: Well, there's more than one way to launch background tasks.  You could use `nohup` and `&` on linux to disconnect the processes, or a COM WScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx object to launch background tasks...

Comment: I want a solution that works both on localhost and the actual server (to simplify testing). I'm posting pseudo code of my planned solution. It still suffers from that "warm up" problem I described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered but I thought I would add my 2p.

You can have pcntl-fork with php in windows using cygwin.

It's a real pain to install, but if like me you just want a php cli script to run, it's your best bet.

I got instructions from [here](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-install-nginx-php-php-fpm-and-mysql-under-1616.html):

Answer (score -1):

**pseudo-code solution:**

```
while (TRUE)
{
   $process_limit = get_process_limit();
   $process_count = get_process_count();

   if process count < process limit:
   {
      // get_row returns a row (as an array) from the DB that needs to be processed
      $row = get_row();
      if($row === array())
      {
         // Nothing to process; sleep
         sleep(2);
      }
      else
      {
         // Process row
         process_count(+1);
         process_row($row);
         process_count(-1);
      }

   }
   elseif process count === process limit
   {
      // Do not add to the process
      exit;
   }
   elseif process count > process limit
   {
      // Means the process limit was decreased
      // Terminate this process instance
      process_count(-1);
      exit;
   }
}
```