# pcntl_fork() is not working in PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, pcntl

I'm running wampp server in Windows OS. Whenever `pcntl_fork()` is tried, a fatal error is shown as `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_fork()`.

I found the PCNTL extension requires *nix platforms. If so is there is any alternatives of PCNTL for windows ?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found there seems to be multiple solutions for forking in Windows. One of them is [psexec](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip) with the following syntax:

```
exec('psexec -d php-cgi.exe somescript.php');
```

I've found this solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458005/forking-in-php-on-windows). Another option would be to use WScript.shell, found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879044/wamp-and-pcntl-fork), with the following syntax:

```
$com = new Com('WScript.shell');
$com->run('php yourscript.php', 10, false);
```

For more documentation and information also check out the relevant [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).